# Select SQL to get discrepancies

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL Server and did a mistake uploading data into a table and struggling to get it right in a short time. Table has 10,000 rows.

I've got two tables with one to many relation. See below:

> Table1 (id1, topic_id, type, description).

The Type can have values ("single" or "multiple")

> Table2 (id, id1, topic_id,  indicator).

`id1` is from Table1. Indicator can have values 0 or 1.

These two tables can be joined based on `id1` and `topic_id`. Note that `Table1 id1` is present in `Table2`. For each entry in `Table1`, there can be more than one entry in `Table2`.

If `Table1.type = "single"`, only one row in `Table2` can have value 1. When I loaded the data the single was loaded wrong in `Table1`. It has a value of multiple. I'm having tough time to write a query to select the dataset in order to correct it.

I can write code to loop through the tables, but wondering if there is a quicker way to do a Select.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the tags. I'm using mysql

Comment: Show us the query you've done, add few data sample (fake data will do) and illustrate the expected result. Make it as minimal as possible as long as you can replicate the situation.

Comment: If it's only 10k rows and you are having troubling figuring out how to fix it, it seems like it would be faster to just clear the table and reimport.  Probably more accurate, too.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the data in Excel. Exported data, deleted all loaded data and did an import. Took me close to 2hours.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not sure what you mean answer is unclear. What about export, import of data in excel is unclear?